# Cannot access kernel space when debugging xv6 with QEMU and GDB

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, qemu, riscv, xv6

I am self-studying the 2019 version of [MIT 6.828/6.S081: Operating System Engineering](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2019/schedule.html).

I was trying to attach GDB to xv6 running on RISC-V using QEMU, to learn about what is going on when context switching happens between user mode and kernel mode.

After doing `make qemu-gdb` and `gdb` in the same directory, my GDB connected to QEMU successfully. However:

```
(gdb) x/2i $pc
=> 0xd8c:   ecall
   0xd90:   ret
```

**The problem is:** Now if I `stepi`, it "jumps over" to `0xd90` instead of stepping into the kernel space.

Additionally, accessing any kernel addresses is not allowed, as if I was debugging a normal userland program:

```
(gdb) i r stvec
stvec          0x3ffffff000 274877902848
(gdb) x/i $stvec
   0x3ffffff000:    Cannot access memory at address 0x3ffffff000
```

**Environment:**

Host VM: `Manjaro 19.0.2`

`sudo pacman -Syy`

`sudo pacman -S riscv64-linux-gnu-binutils riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc riscv64-linux-gnu-gdb qemu-arch-extra`

GDB: `9.1`

QEMU: `4.2.0`

GCC: `9.2.0`

Much appreciate anyone could share some insight about what is going on here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just fixed a single step issue for qemu. Not sure if it is your problem. Check it out here: https://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-devel@nongnu.org/msg681645.html

Comment: Did you manage to get around this problem? I'm experiencing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you run your code on `ubuntu`, that is the problem I experienced, then I change to `mac`, and flow mit tools tutorials, finally, it works.

1. run  `make CPUS=1 qemu-gdb` in one window.
2. run  `riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb` in another window.

ignore the Python Exception

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this problem by building the riscv toolchain as explained [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2020/tools.html).

Building the toolchain as explained in the site, generates a generic ELF/Newlib toolchain identified with the prefix `riscv64-unknown-elf-` in contrast to the more sophisticated Linux-ELF/glibc toolchain identified by the prefix `riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-`. The `Newlib` build allows the debugger to `stepi` into kernel space.

For [crossdev](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Crossdev) users it is possible to build the toolchain with `Newlib` support by running:

```
crossdev --ex-gcc --ex-gdb --target riscv64-unknown-elf
```